# Having a list of strings stored and synced in a file

Tags: c++, file, list, serialization

I need to get all items of a `list<string>` data structure stored in a file and synchronize it every time the list gets updated. I am looking for recommendations as to what the best approach is to do this in terms of performance. My main concern is how to insert and delete strings into/from file as fast as it's done in a structure like `std::list`.

Comment: Maybe use an SQLite database?

Comment: Writing to a file is slow - you will never be able to do it as fast as with a list in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can go for memory mapped IO.
What you can do is Create a memory mapped file.
Pre allocate the list pointing to this memory mapped file.
So your data is persisted to the file.

I have done this with a list of structures for which the size is known.

Since you say a string you may have some issues but i think you can use a char array with predefined size to overcome this.